# Register .app domain for trademark holders

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains, trademark

According to https://www.registry.google/, Google is planning to be the registry for a new `.app` domain. Registration will commence with a "sunrise" period on March 29 for those holding trademarks.

However, I can't find anywhere I can actually submit my registration. Where can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of .APP registrars should supposedly appear at https://www.registry.google/about/register.html at some point.
In the mean time, 2 options:

- either contact your registrar of choice, the one with whom you are already doing business, that you know and appreciate; they should be able to at least help you and let you know if they will either provide this TLD at some point or give you advices on where to go to have it
- consult the ICANN list of registrars at http://www.internic.net/regist.html (a very ugly website, but the authoritative source) or https://www.icann.org/registrar-reports/accreditation-qualified-list.html, as for newer gTLDs such as `.app` registrars have a very lightweight procedure at ICANN to become accredited in them; or just start from the Google list of registrars for their other TLDs as there is a good chance they will carry `.app` too!

When a gTLD opens it has to (ICANN requirements) go to specific launch phases, first one for trademarks, called the sunrise (which can be further split based on various criterias) and then one for "claims" where prospective owners will be notified in case they may be infringing some trademarks, in order to give explicit consent before going further. This later "claims" phase can run undefinitively.

During the trademark case, to apply for a domain name, you will need to get an SMD file that you obtain after registering some kind of trademarks at the TMCH office. Some registrars or trademarks agent can provide you this service for a fee.

Also in case of difficulties finding regitrars you first point of contact should be the registry itself. So try to contact them and see how they can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I could only find [Trademark Clearinghouse](http://www.trademark-clearinghouse.com/content/priority-registration-trademark-holders) offering SMD files. It is also [linked to](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/about/trademark-clearinghouse) by ICANN. However, it seems fishy because [some options call for a deposit of $15,000](https://secure.trademark-clearinghouse.com/tmch/public/contract) just to register.

Comment: For others stumbling on the above comment, the followup question at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114144/obtaining-an-smd-file-to-use-for-sunrise-domain-registration discuss this point

Answer (score 1):

101domain is currently allowing for trademark holders to register their .app domains.

If you scroll down on the following page you'll see that we are currently in the sunrise grace period for trademark holders:

https://www.101domain.com/app.htm

I've held some domains with 101domain over the years. They seem fine.

Comment: Thanks, they do have .app. I wonder how they verify that you are owner of trademark? [The reviews](https://www.quora.com/Domain-Registrars-Is-101domain-a-reliable-service-1) for this company look really terrible though.

Comment: According to 101domain "This phase is for trademark holders who have verified their trademark with the Trademark Clearinghouse (TMCH). You must submit a valid SMD file issued by the TMCH to register a domain during this phase." - While I've used them for some domains in the past, they are not one of my primary registars.